# Displaying data from an external XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, ftp

I need to display data from an XML document that is on an external FTP server... can this be done?
I want to display the entire document as a list. I have really struggled to find out how this is done, or even if it can be done.
SOrry for the rather non-specific question, but if someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('ftp://example.com/somefile.xml')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has FTP functions:

ftp_get http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Once you have the file you have a couple of options:

Parse the XML into (I assume) an HTML list http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Or use an XSLT transform http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php